# Optimising calculation of complex powers of complex numbers in javascript for accuracy

Tags: javascript, math, optimization

I've got this code which computes complex powers of complex numbers:

```
var ss = a.re*a.re + a.im*a.im;
var arg1 = math.arg(a);
var mag = Math.pow(ss,b.re/2) * Math.exp(-b.im*arg1);
var arg = b.re*arg1 + (b.im * Math.log(ss))/2;
return math.complex(mag*Math.cos(arg), mag*Math.sin(arg));
```

(complex numbers look like {re: 1, im: 1}, and math.arg just gives Math.atan2(n.im.n.re). math.complex is the constructor for complex numbers)

It isn't particularly complicated, and I'm not well-versed in efficiency/accuracy analyses.

I'd like to get better results on, in particular, integer powers of complex numbers, because that can be done much more accurately with a binomial expansion. Has anyone got anything like that already written **in javascript**, before I go off making my own? I'm not hugely worried about speed, more about accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

So your code is turning the complex number into polar form, then applying basic exponent rules.

You claim that you'd prefer something like (a+bi)^n = [an nth degree polynomial expansion]

You say you are concerned about accuracy.

There are three sources of inaccuracy I can think of

- javascript numbers: If you're using javascript, it is dangerous to be concerned about accuracy. Integers are actually floats, and you can get precision errors with integers because of this if you work with very large numbers. Be warned.
- Math functions: How accurately Math.pow and Math.atan2 calculate their results. You can research this if you need to.
- rounding error: If you perform a large number of operations which expands the range/image of the operation in relation to the domain/preimage, rounding error can be compounded.

There is also a source of inefficiency to be concerned about: calculating z^n with a polynomial expansion will take O(n) time and O(n) space, which is absolutely terrible.

You could make it take O(log(n)) time and O(1) or O(log(n)) space (still quite bad, as opposed to the previous O(1) time and space), by decomposing the exponent n into its binary representation.

In the end, you are still calculating a floating point representation. There is no reason to perform a long series of operations to calculate it, when you could just perform (basically) one operation; unless that operation is incredibly inaccurate, you should expect your error to be less the fewer operations you perform.

What would have a much more profound impact on accuracy is the distribution of numbers you expect to work with (very small, very large, both, etc.) and choice of representation (e.g. if you choose to naturally represent them in polar or cartesian form). If for example you plan to do lots of adding and subtracting, you may get more less rounding error and more speed with cartesian. If you plan to do lots of multiplication and division and exponentiation, or work on the exponential scale, you may get less rounding error and more speed with polar.

Comment: What do you mean? `(1+i)^5` isn't equal to `1^5 + i^5`.

Comment: @ChristianPerfect: oh sorry, I didn't see where you said "I'm not hugely worried about speed, more about accuracy"; I assumed you implied you were worried about efficiency because of your comment about efficiency/accuracy analysis. I will edit my answer...

Comment: This is for a general maths package as part of a browser-based maths assessment system, so I don't expect to be using particularly big numbers. I reckon integer coefficients everywhere will be the most common use.
The reason this was even an issue was that (1+i)^5 evaluated to {re: -4.0000000001, im: -4} using the logs-and-trig method, which is quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about integer powers, the most accurate would be to just multiply them:

```
var Re = 0, Im = 1;
var newRe = 1, newIm = 0;
var retRe = 1, retIm = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    newRe = retRe * Re - retIm * Im;
    newIm = retRe * Im + retIm * Re;
    retRe = newRe;
    retIm = newIm;
}
```